# Getting dots to follow bigger dot

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

So this is a program I made for some dots to be attracted to a bigger dot and for that bigger dot to grow. The issue I'm facing right now is that the dots don't follow the bigger dot but rather seem to move away from it. The way I'm getting it to get closer is by translating the points, one to (0,0), the other to [t2.xcor() - t1.xcor() , t2.ycor()- t1.ycor()] , and then finding C with the Pythagorean theorem, and then using arc cosine to find the angle it needs to face in order to move towards the bigger dot.

```
from turtle import *
import sys
from math import *
#grows t1 shape + has it follow cursor
def grow(x, y):
    t1.ondrag(None)
    t1.goto(x,y)
    global big, nig
    t1.shapesize(big,nig)
    big += .004
    nig += .004
    t1.ondrag(grow)
    follow()

#has create()'d dots follow t1
def follow():
    global count
    #t1.ondrag(None)
    screen.tracer(0,0)
    for p in lx:
        #print(lx[0:5])
        t2.goto(p, ly[count])
        t2.dot(4, "white")
        if ly[count] != 0:
            yb = abs(t2.ycor() - t1.ycor())
            xb = abs((t2.xcor() - t1.xcor()))
            c = sqrt((xb**2 + yb**2))
            #print(y,x,c)
            #print(lx)
            t2.seth(360 - degrees(acos(yb/c)))
        else:
            t2.seth(0)
        t2.forward(20)
        t2.dot(4, "purple")
        lx.pop(count)
        ly.pop(count)
        lx.insert(count, t2.xcor())
       ly.insert(count, t2.ycor())
        count += 1
            #print(lx[0:5])
    #screen.update()
    screen.tracer(1,10)
    count = 0
    #t1.ondrag(follow)
#quits program
def quit():
    screen.bye()
    sys.exit(0)

#create()'s dots with t2
def create():
    screen.tracer(0,0)
    global nux, nuy, count3
    while nuy > -400:
        t2.goto(nux, nuy)
        if t2.pos() != t1.pos():
            t2.dot(4, "purple")
        lx.append(t2.xcor())
        ly.append(t2.ycor())
        nux += 50
        count3 += 1
        if count3 == 17:
            nuy = nuy - 50
            nux = -400
            count3 = 0
    screen.tracer(1, 10)

#variables    
count3 = count = 0
big = nig = .02
lx = []
ly = []
nux = -400
nuy = 300

screen = Screen()
screen.screensize(4000,4000)


t2 = Turtle()
t2.ht()
t2.pu()
t2.speed(0)
t2.shape("turtle")

t1 = Turtle()
t1.shape("circle")
t1.penup()
t1.speed(0)
t1.color("purple")
t1.shapesize(.2, .2)

create()

screen.listen()
screen.onkeypress(quit, "Escape")

t1.ondrag(grow)
#t1.ondrag(follow)

#screen.update()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I didn't read your code but from your description I suspect you need to use `atan2` rather than `arccos`: you need to be able to distinguish between an angle `phi` and the corresponding "opposite direction" `phi + pi` (in radians). Arcus cosine will only give you an angle between 0 and pi, whereas you want to be able to get any orientation. That's exactly what `atan2` will do for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two (similar) issues with your code.  First, you can toss the fancy math as you're reinventing turtle's `.towards()` method which gives you the angle you seek.  Second, you're reinventing *stamps* which, unlike most turtle elements, can be cleared cleanly off the screen via `clearstamp()`.  Also, you're using parallel arrays of coordinates which indicates lack of a proper data structure.  I've replaced this with a single array containing tuples of positions and stamps.

I've adjusted the dynamics of your program, making the dots act independently (on a timer) and not rely on the movement of the cursor.  I.e. they move towards the cursor whether it's moving or not.  Also, I've made the cursor only grow when a dot reaches it and disappears:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def move(x, y):
    """ has it follow cursor """

    t1.ondrag(None)

    t1.goto(x, y)

    screen.update()

    t1.ondrag(move)

def grow():
    """ grows t1 shape """

    global t1_size

    t1_size += 0.4
    t1.shapesize(t1_size / CURSOR_SIZE)

    screen.update()

def follow():
    """ has create()'d dots follow t1 """

    global circles

    new_circles = []

    for (x, y), stamp in circles:
        t2.clearstamp(stamp)

        t2.goto(x, y)
        t2.setheading(t2.towards(t1))
        t2.forward(2)

        if t2.distance(t1) > t1_size // 2:
            new_circles.append((t2.position(), t2.stamp()))
        else:
            grow()  # we ate one, make t1 fatter

    screen.update()

    circles = new_circles

    if circles:
        screen.ontimer(follow, 50)

def create():
    """ create()'s dots with t2 """

    count = 0
    nux, nuy = -400, 300

    while nuy > -400:
        t2.goto(nux, nuy)

        if t2.distance(t1) > t1_size // 2:
            circles.append((t2.position(), t2.stamp()))

        nux += 50
        count += 1
        if count == 17:
            nuy -= 50
            nux = -400
            count = 0

    screen.update()

# variables
t1_size = 4
circles = []

screen = Screen()
screen.screensize(900, 900)

t2 = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
t2.shapesize(4 / CURSOR_SIZE)
t2.speed('fastest')
t2.color('purple')
t2.penup()

t1 = Turtle('circle')
t1.shapesize(t1_size / CURSOR_SIZE)
t1.speed('fastest')
t1.color('orange')
t1.penup()

t1.ondrag(move)

screen.tracer(False)

create()

follow()

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]

You should be able to rework this code to do whatever it is you want.  I strongly recommend you spend some time reading the Turtle documentation so you don't need to reinvent its many features.

Comment: Thank you so much, you went above and beyond, and it ended up solving what I was trying to attempt. Thank you you so much!